# Object operator in PHP (->)

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Sorry for being so pedantic about this, but I'm confused about the object operator (->). What exactly is it doing and how (to avoid errors and misusing) do I use it?

Comment: Please reference [What does this symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to use the object operator, you will need to create and instantiate a class, as follows:

```
class MyClass {
  public $myVar;

  public function myMethod() {

  }
}

$instance = new MyClass();

$instance->myVar = "Hello World"; // Assign "Hello World" to "myVar"
$instance->myMethod(); // Run "myMethod()"
```

Let me explain the above code:

1. First, a class with a name of "MyClass" is created, with a variable of "myVar" and a method (basically a function within a class) with a name of "myMethod".
2. "$instance" is created, and then it is assigned a new instance of the "MyClass" class.
3. $instance->myVar, with the object operator accesses the public instance variable within the $instance object, and assigns it a value of "Hello World". Similarly, the "myMethod" is called within the $instance object, also using the object operator.

The object operator is simply PHPs way of accessing, running, or assigning "stuff" within an object.

Hope that helps.

Comment: To all of you, thanks a lot :) That was very helpful.

Answer (score 6):

its just like the . in other languages. eg, if you have a object called ball with method bounce(), in most languages it would be

```
ball.bounce();
```

in php it is

```
ball->bounce();
```

Comment: In other languages, `.` would also do what `::` does in PHP, so this comparison might get confusing.

Comment: @Max, no, `=>` has nothing to do with `->`, it's something completely different.

Comment: As I said, I was confused... @miku posted a link further down which clarified it :)

Comment: ahh, sorry about the confusion, just thought a simple example would be easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you so much, coming from Java this is a great way of explaining it!

Answer (score 2):

> The object operator, "->", is used in object scope **to access methods and properties** of an object. It's meaning is to say that what is on the right of the operator is a member of the object instantiated into the variable on the left side of the operator.

From: http://www.robert-gonzalez.com/2009/03/04/php-operators-double-and-single-arrow/

Other languages use the dot notation for this, like `obj.meth()`.